# For android development can I use JPG image instead of PNG image on image views?

Tags: android, image, performance

The main purpose of this question is to know what is the best option to choose between PNG and JPG for android development considering the following scenarios

1) is it a good option to use jpg image as background?
2) Will .jpg image take more time to load compared to .png?
3) Will .jpg take more time for rendering/loading compare to .png?

I have seen big difference in image size when we are using png images.

One of my .png image size is **4.1 MBs** and that same image with .jpg image format the size is reduced to **2.9MBs**

**Need suggestion from Experts specially.**

**Info:** To reduce app size. i am still compressing images by using [compress png](http://compresspng.com) and [compress jpeg](http://compressjpeg.com/)

Image size difference is huge. ie. 4.1 MBs png -> 2.9 MBs jpg after compressing it reduced to **654.6 KBs**..

To set image as **BACKGROUND** i didn't found any issue...

Comment: I think we should migrate to 9patch images.

Comment: I just use [compress jpeg](http://compressjpeg.com) right now and it is great! Thank you for putting this info.

Comment: Welcome @FilipedeLimaBrito

Answer (score 13):

It's just a question of quality and details.
Just for my opinion, for a big background resolution is better to use a JPG, if you don't need any transparency on the image, with the right compromise between quality and size of file,

**PNG format** is a lossless compression file format, which makes it a common choice for use on the Web. PNG is a good choice for storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a small file size.

**JPG format** is a lossy compressed file format. This makes it useful for storing photographs at a smaller size than a BMP. JPG is a common choice for use on the Web because it is compressed. For storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a smaller file size, GIF or PNG are better choices because they are lossless.

From:http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is image quality. The PNG format uses a lossless compression, while JPEG uses a lossy one optimized for photos. It depends what is shown on the image if JPEG is a valid alternative. In artificially generated images of geometric figures like logos the artifacts coming from JPEG compression can be easily seen.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of quality of the images. If you're ok with the loss of quality just use it instead.

> A bitmap file is a `.png`, `.jpg`, or `.gif` file. Android creates a `Drawable` resource for any of these files when you save them in the `res/drawable/` directory.

Comment: Actually i can not post image over here otherwise you can not easily identify that which is compress image and which is original image... but image size difference is huge. ie. 4.1 png -> 2.9 jpg after compressing it  reduced to 654.6 kb..

Comment: @BhaveshJethani if it looks good, there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: thank you.. i just afraid about 1 thing is that  .. is jpg image take more time to load as image.