# Do I need to do anything more to create/use drawable-nodpi folder?

Tags: android, drawable

I have some images which I don't intend to be scaled, and I've read they are supposed to be in the drawable-nodpi folder. That folder didn't exist in my project yet.

I created it, and moved the images into that folder. Beside the file name it says (nodpi) in brackets. Does this mean the image will not scale when being loaded into an imageview? Does this also mean it takes less memory to load into an imageview, if the image is just center cropped?

[image: (nodpi) in brackets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The images isn't scaled according the device density. Here the excerpt from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities):

> If you have some drawable resources that the system should never scale
>   (perhaps because you perform some adjustments to the image yourself at
>   runtime), you should place them in a directory with the nodpi
>   configuration qualifier. Resources with this qualifier are considered
>   density-agnostic and the system will not scale them.

And don't forget to use `png` file type instead of `jpeg`.

Comment: Why should I use png instead of jpegs? If I am loading from drawables into imageviews, without creating any bitmap objects myself, is there still a risk of memory leaks somehow?

Comment: You have transparency with png. jpeg don't support it. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369670/for-android-development-can-i-use-jpg-image-instead-of-png-image-on-image-views?rq=1 for details.